# Maximum number of retry attempts

Tags: robotframework

I encountered a freezing test but actually it was stuck in a retry loop.

`Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    | 60 sec     | 12 sec`

The first parameter is the timeout for an attempt and the second is retry interval. However, if the task is something like "Xpath Should Match X Times" on a large data set it might never succeed in given time and next attempt starts from scratch again.

Is there way to limit the maximum number of retry attempts in this kind of situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your situation is a bit strange because theoretically there is no such thing as "infinite retry loop" with Wait Until Keyword Succeeds because the first parameter is not "timeout for an attempt" but rather "global timeout for all the attempts". So in your case, it would try every 12 seconds and stop after 60 secs elapsed. Maybe you should reconsider the value you use with this information.

To answer your question, there is no way (AFAIK) to give a max number of attempts. I had such a need for some keywords and I came up with my own custom keyword:

```
Run_keyword_n_times_and_stop_if_success
    [Arguments]  ${keyword}  ${number_tries}
    :FOR  ${index}  IN RANGE  ${number_tries}
    \  ${result}  ${error_message} =  Run Keyword And Ignore Error  ${keyword}
    \  Pass Execution If  '${result}' == 'PASS'  keyword execution was successful
    Fail  ${error_message}
```

This works only with keywords having no arguments, but maybe that could be helpful for you (either because you don't have args, or because you could elaborate on that first version)

Comment: Yep, you are right that my situation was strange. It actually turned out to be "slow script error popup" on the browser that blocked the test but my initial guess was wrong and I misinterpreted the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Retry keyword. To use it with a keyword with arguments.

```
Run Keyword N Times And Stop If Success
[Arguments]    ${number_tries}    ${keyword}    @{args}
: FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    ${number_tries}
\    ${result}    ${error_message} =    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    ${keyword}    @{args}
\    Pass Execution If    '${result}' == 'PASS'    keyword execution was successful
Fail    ${errorLog_message}
```

Sample usage:

```
@{args}    Create List    @{User}    ${Url}    ${Browser}
Run Keyword N Times And Stop If Success    5    Login    @{args}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [April 2015](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/commit/23f8d1ce5777c4f0fa4b50731cb92e6429382089), this has been implemented as an argument for the keyword.
An example of usage could be seen as:

`Wait Until Keyword Succeeds | 5x | 30 sec | Flaky Keyword`

More information on the keyword is available in the [BuiltIn documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds).